# How to continue same section to next page in Latex?

Tags: tables, sectioning, page-breaking, resume

[image]So for resume I chose one of the pre-defined samples and started to edit it. And now within the same section of " Experiences"  my resume exceeds the page but the content in not continuing on the next page rather it somehow gets hidden whatever content is more than to fir in the same page. So how can I move the some part of the section to new page. Also an extra page is created before this section .
My code is following

```
\section{Internships And Projects}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{15cm}}
 \textsc{.....} &\textsc{ \underline{...... }} |....... | \textit{..... }\\ ....
  &  \normalsize{$\bullet$ 
}\\multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
....
.
.
.
.
\end{tabular}
```

..... represents the text inserted. Already tied with\pagebreak at the location of where a I want beak but that didn't help .

Comment: tabular can not break over a page

Comment: you must surely get an error from `\\multicolumn{1}` which can not be used at that point?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how can I break over the page and continue on next page ? Please help. No I am not getting errors for multicolumn

Comment: since you posted no usable code hard to say what you should change, you could use a `longtable` instead of `tabular` which allows page breaks or use a description enviornment instead od a table that would allow page breaking ewithin each item. If you are not getting errors then your code is not as you show here, you can not have `\multicolumn` after `}` it has to be the first command in its cell.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sir can I connect with you though email and show you the exact code as seen in latex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The reason there's no error is that it's not `\multicolumn` but `\\multicolumn` so Ananya would be getting a line break and then `multicolumn1c` output on a line by itself instead of what I presume was the intended output of eliminating the vertical line. I'm guessing it was meant to be `\\\multicolumn`.

Comment: @Ananya, you should edit your question to show enough of the document to replicate the issue, but the problem is very much the use of `tabular` which doesn't break over linebreaks. Try going to a command line and typing `texdoc longtable` to see how to use `longtable` or, if that's possible, you can get the documentation online at https://texdoc.org

Comment: @DonHosek seems I need new glasses

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My book has an appendix which is attempting to cover the why behind every (or almost every) error you can get with LaTeX so I've been doing a lot of things “wrong” with LaTeX. I think sometimes I see more incorrect LaTeX code than correct code.

Comment: I have added an image for your reference. That's what I exactly want